# Get_the_term_list inexplicably adds values in foreach

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, terms

I'm trying to get three values from all my custom posts, to populate a Google Map with the places where I've been. All is going fairly well, except for an issue I'm having with `get_the_term_list`. For some reason it adds the number **"1"** in front of each correctly returned value.

As an example, my below code will output the following for "name":

```
Key: name, Value: 1
<a rel="tag" href="http://localhost:8888/mntn/mountain/grossglockner">Grossglockner</a>
<br>
```

The problem code:

```
<?php 
//get custom posts ids as an array
$loop = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'   => 'trips',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids'
    )
);
//loop through each post
foreach($loop as $p){
    //get the meta and taxonomy data
     $name = get_the_term_list($p, "mountains",true);
     $wtr_longitud = get_post_meta($p,"wtr_longitude",true);
     $wtr_latitud = get_post_meta($p,"wtr_latitude",true);

    //Add to Array
    $map_array[] = array ("name" => $name, "latitude" => $wtr_latitud, "longitude" => $wtr_longitud);
}
        //Print array
        foreach($map_array as $y) {
                    foreach( $y as $key => $value){
                    echo "Key: $key, Value: $value <br />";
                    }
            }
?>
```

Comment: For now I used trim(); to remove it, but obviously I'd prefer to know why this got added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the get_the_term_list() function, which is defined with the following arguments:

```
get_the_term_list( $id = 0, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '' )
```

You're defining the `$before` argument as *true* which PHP prints as *1* so that's why it's printing a 1 before the list. You should either remove the argument altogether:

```
get_the_term_list( $p, 'mountains' );
```

or replace it with a string:

```
get_the_term_list( $p, 'mountains', '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' );
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I copy pasted it from another place where I'm outputting it (and where it works without the "1"), so I probably didn't dig deep enough.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!